# Kinetic Energy Alternative Expression

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

[image]

**Attempt:** **I've managed to show everything except for the last part.** I need to show an alternative expression for $T$ as shown below. I've tried showing the relevant scalar product is the same as taking the scalar product of the velocity but it hasn't worked out, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Dr. MV Sorry for the comment, I didn't know you were planning to do it in parts. I just wanted to make it clear I had a problem with the last part only as you posted a solution for the first part. Sorry again.

Comment: Done.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, we note that since $\vec B$ is constant

$$m\vec r''=q\vec r'\times\vec B\implies m\vec r'=q\vec r\times\vec B \tag 1$$

Next, using $(1)$, we observe that

$$\begin{align}
\vec L\cdot \vec B&=(m\vec r \times \vec r')\cdot \vec B\\\\
&=-m\vec r'\cdot (\vec r\times \vec B)\\\\
&=-\frac{m^2}{q}(\vec r'\cdot \vec r') \tag 2
\end{align}$$

We also have

$$\left|\vec r\times \vec B\right|^2=\frac{m^2}{q^2}(\vec r'\cdot \vec r') \tag 3$$

Therefore, using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have

$$\vec L\cdot \vec B+\frac12 q\left|\vec r\times \vec B\right|^2=-\frac12 \frac{m^2}{q}(\vec r'\cdot \vec r') \tag 4$$

Finally,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec r'\cdot \vec r'\right) &= 2\left(\vec r'\cdot \vec r''\right)\\\\
&=2\vec r'\cdot \frac{q}{m}(\vec r'\times \vec B)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

so that $\vec L\cdot \vec B+\frac12 q\left|\vec r\times \vec B\right|^2$ is a constant of motion as was to be shown.

---

For the second part, we already showed that the Kinetic energy is a constant of motion since we showed that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec r\cdot \vec r\right)=0$$

Now we define a unit vector $\hat u=\frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|}$.  Since $\hat u$ is a unit vector, we observe that since $\hat u\cdot \hat u=1$, then

$$\hat u'\cdot \hat u=\frac12 \frac{d}{dt}(\hat u\cdot \hat u)=0$$

and

$$\frac12 \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\hat u\cdot \hat u)=\hat u\cdot \hat u''+\hat u'\cdot \hat u'\implies \hat u\cdot \hat u''=-\hat u'\cdot \hat u' \tag 5$$

We also will make use of the identities

$$r'=\frac{d}{dt}\left|\vec r\right|=\hat u\cdot \vec v \tag 6$$

and

$$r \hat u' =\vec v-r'\hat u \tag 7$$

Then, using $(5)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\hat u\cdot \left((\hat u\cdot \vec v)\vec v-r^2\hat u''\right)&=(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2+r^2\hat u'\cdot \hat u'\\\\
&=(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2+(\vec v-r'\hat u)\cdot (\vec v-r'\hat u)\\\\
&=(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2+(\vec v\cdot \vec v-2r'\hat u\cdot \vec v+r'^2)\\\\
&=\vec v\cdot \vec v+(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2-2(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2+(\hat u\cdot \vec v)^2\\\\
&=\vec v\cdot \vec v
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can write the kinetic energy $T=\frac12 m\vec v\cdot \vec v$ as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{T=\frac12 m\left(\hat u\cdot \left((\hat u\cdot \vec v)\vec v-r^2\hat u''\right)\right)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: ive already shown that, check my post. my problem is with the last part of the question

Comment: The kinetic energy is constant, but not zero.

Comment: I know. I've been watching... However, you might consider using $\dot{\hat{u}}$ and $\ddot{\hat{u}}$ for the time derivatives, instead of $\hat{u}'$ and $\hat{u}''$, as those are the standard notation for problems in physics.

Comment: @wltrup That notation is not the standard in physics.  I've seen a variety of notations.  And here it is a bit cumbersome.  The prime notation works fine.

Comment: No offence, but yes, it is the standard notation for time-derivatives in physics. (I should know. In a former life I used to be a theoretical physicist) Yes, occasionally you see primes but that's far less common. I agree it's very cumbersome here, which is why I was just suggesting rather than saying it had to be that way. :)

Comment: Well, I was a professor (EM Field Theory, Ph.D.) in a former life and taught using either notation.  Yes, Newton's notation is seen in QM and QED etc., especially when we see the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formulations.  but for EM, I don't believe that there was a strong preference.  The dots (and the primes) become very cumbersome when higher order derivatives are of interest.

Comment: Not trying to make a big deal. It was just a suggestion. ;)

Comment: @wltrup No worry.  We're friends here!  The dots are a typing challenge for me.  ;-)))

Comment: @Dr.MV for the last part, without deducing those identities in the first place, would you say your experience of solving questions before like this helped or was their some sort of inspiration from the expression?

Comment: @whizkid I'm not quite sure as to the precise meaning of your question, but experience does help.  The challenge here was working with the unit vector and its time derivatives.